# How to automatically insert underscores between my method name words?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

In Visual studio how can I automatically insert underscores between my method name Words?

For example I will write `public void ChangeEmail Should Update Email()` then press a shortcut and it will convert to `public void ChangeEmail_Should_Update_Email()`.

Comment: That's a very non-standard naming convention for C#.  Most naming conventions for public methods use Pascal casing: http://www.csharpfriends.com/articles/getarticle.aspx?articleid=336#8

Comment: i am writing it like that just in my unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this.  You set your naming convention, type it incorrectly and CTRL-Enter will fix it.  Among the millions of other features ReSharper adds to VS...

Comment: the only problem with resharper is that you still have to write code

Comment: good to know that reSharper can do it, i didn't test resharper on VS 2010, is it working fine?, asking about performance and compatibility.

Comment: Yes, ReSharper works great on 2010 and they just recently released 5.1 which has a lot of bug fixes (none of which were ones we ran into though).